# Java Recursion iterator with my own tree

Tags: java, recursion

I have two pieces of code that in my mind do the same thing but it doesn't.
I am trying to create an iterator for my custom set tree. Here's the code.

```
public LinkedList<AnyType> traverse (TheNode<AnyType> node,LinkedList<AnyType> theList){ 
    if (node.left != null)
        return traverse (node.left,theList);        
    theList.push(node.element);
    if (node.right != null)
        return traverse (node.right,theList);       

    return theList;

}

public void traverseNrTwo (TheNode<AnyType> node){ 
    if (node.left != null){
        traverseNrTwo (node.left);
    }
    list.push(node.element);
    if (node.right != null){
        traverseNrTwo (node.right);
    }
}
```

`traverse` only goes through the left side of the tree and adds it to the list but `traveseNrTwo` goes through the whole tree. So, my question is, why do they do two different things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't return the result of the recursive calls, since it causes the recursion to visit just the left side of the tree.

```
public LinkedList<AnyType> traverse (TheNode<AnyType> node,LinkedList<AnyType> theList){ 
    if (node.left != null)
        traverse (node.left,theList); // if you return traverse(node.left,theList) here,
                                      // you end the recursion without adding the current
                                      // node and visiting the right sub-tree 
    theList.push(node.element);
    if (node.right != null)
        traverse (node.right,theList);       

    return theList;   
}
```

Also note that since you are passing the `LinkedList<AnyType>` as an argument to your method (i.e. you are not creating a new `LinkedList` instance inside your method), you don't have to return it. You can simply change the return type to `void`.